# Angular routes: child route is loaded but not rendered

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an issue in routing, as you can see in the following code that I'm redirecting the empty path to home as full path match, then in the home is loading my MainComponent and some children, which im trying to load, now because my first child has an empty path, its been used when redirecting to home in first place, then this will match with the next peace of code down below which will load HomeFiveComponent and it does as I have placed some logs in the component and it gets printed, but nothing get printed but the index page.

app.routes:

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './shop/shop.module#ShopModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'pages',
        loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'pages/404'
  }
];
```

shop.routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    component: HomeFiveComponent
  },

]
```

MainComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsService } from '../shared/services/products.service';
import { CartService } from '../shared/services/cart.service';
import { WishlistService } from '../shared/services/wishlist.service';
import { BrandsService } from '../shared/services/brands.service';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss'],
  providers: [ProductsService, CartService, WishlistService, BrandsService]
})
@Injectable()
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  public url: any;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.url = event.url;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    $.getScript('assets/js/script.js');
  }

}
```

MainCompnent.html:

```
<app-header-one></app-header-one>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer-one></app-footer-one>
```

script.js:

```
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*=====================
   01.Pre loader
   ==========================*/
  $('.loader-wrapper').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });


  /*=====================
   02.Tap on Top
   ==========================*/
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
      $('.tap-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.tap-top').fadeOut();
    }
  });
  $('.tap-top').on('click', function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
  });


  /*=====================
   03. toggle nav
   ==========================*/
  $('.toggle-nav').on('click', function() {
    $('.sm-horizontal').css("right", "0px");
  });
  $(".mobile-back").on('click', function() {
    $('.sm-horizontal').css("right", "-410px");
  });



  /*=====================
   04. footer according
   ==========================*/
  var contentwidth = jQuery(window).width();
  if ((contentwidth) < '750') {
    jQuery('.footer-title h4').append('<span class="according-menu"></span>');
    jQuery('.footer-title').on('click', function() {
      jQuery('.footer-title').removeClass('active');
      jQuery('.footer-contant').slideUp('normal');
      if (jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
      }
    });
    jQuery('.footer-contant').hide();
  } else {
    jQuery('.footer-contant').show();
  }

  if ($(window).width() < '1183') {
    jQuery('.menu-title h5').append('<span class="according-menu"></span>');
    jQuery('.menu-title').on('click', function() {
      jQuery('.menu-title').removeClass('active');
      jQuery('.menu-content').slideUp('normal');
      if (jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
      }
    });
    jQuery('.menu-content').hide();
  } else {
    jQuery('.menu-content').show();
  }

  /*=====================
   05.RTL js
   ==========================*/
  $(".rtl-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $("html").attr("dir", "rtl");
      $("body").addClass('rtl');
    } else {
      $("html").attr("dir", "ltr");
      $("body").removeClass('rtl');
    }
  });
});
```

Edit:

My code works fine if I have the following configurations:

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    redirectTo: 'home/product/shop',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'product',
        loadChildren: './shop/shop.module#ShopModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'pages',
        loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'pages/404'
  }
];
```

and shop.routes:

```
  { 
    path: 'shop',
    component: HomeFiveComponent
  }
```

Comment: can you add MainComponent template to the code ? and what is this doing canActivateChild: [MainComponent, HomeFiveComponent, ShopModule] according to you?

Comment: @SGalea I tried to add canActivateChild but it does not make any difference

Comment: Remove that line, canActivateChild  is for guards to block navigation access based on conditions. Show me main.component.html

Comment: side note, don't use `jquery` with `Angular`, it means you are not doing it wrong

Comment: I belive you forgot to have router-outlet, can you share your components htmls

Comment: hence why I'm asking for main.component.html

Comment: also what is `canActivateChild: [MainComponent, HomeFiveComponent, ShopModule]`???

Comment: @SGalea hence upvoted ;)

Comment: Apart from your question we also want to know what  $.getScript('assets/js/script.js'); is loading so we help you with that also

Comment: I have added the html and removed the canActivateChild from my code

Comment: Also why @Injectable() on component? remove it.

Comment: @SGalea I used it for local storage but I don't need it any longer, I have added the script.js

Comment: OK JQuery and Angular don't play well together. The reason is that JQuery manipulates the DOM directly while Angular is managing that for us and can lead to all sort of weird things.

Comment: @SGalea but my code is working fine if have the above code in the edit section

Comment: Ok replicate the issue on stackblitz so we can take a look.

Comment: @SGalea I could not replicate the issue on stackblitz but I can share my code on GitHub

Comment: @RezaRahmati any suggestions?